# can anyone help me? why my button cant do anthing when i add multiselectpicklist?

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, custom-controller

i got problem, when i add multiselectpicklist into my vf page, then my button cant do anything.
here is my vfpage :

```
<apex:page controller="PreProcessController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="PreProcessPayroll" title="Pre Process Payroll">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false">

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Payroll Name" for="listPeriod"/>
                <apex:selectList id="listPeriod" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPeriod}" style="width:150px">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Period}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll" value="{!ProcessAll}">
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>                
        </apex:pageBlockSection>    

        <apex:panelGroup id="listElements">
        <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}"
                                rightLabel="Selected Employee" rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}"
                                size="11" width="450px"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton id="btnPreProcess" value="Run Pre Process" action="{!RunPreProcess}"/>           
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>               

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:outputText >{!message}</apex:outputText>
```

and my controller here :

```
public with sharing class PreProcessController
{     
      public String selectedPeriod{get; set;}
      public String message{get; set;}
      public boolean ProcessAll {get; set;}
      public SelectOption[] allEmployee {get; set;}
      public SelectOption[] selectedEmployee {get; set;}


public LIST<SelectOption> getPeriod()
{
    LIST<SelectOption> listPeriod = new LIST<SelectOption>();
    listPeriod.add(new SelectOption('', '- None -'));
    for (PYSETPAYPERIOD__c perCode : [SELECT Id, Name, Process_Flag__c FROM PYSETPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Process_Flag__c < 4 OR Process_Flag__c = NULL ORDER BY Name]) {         
        listPeriod.add(new selectOption(perCode.id, perCode.Name));       
    }
    return listPeriod;
}




public void RunPreProcess()
{
    message ='It work!';    
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using System.debug instead of using outputMessage into the page?

Comment: already, still not work, it seem like my button is disabled when i create multiselectpicklist in my vf page, when i remove that, my button work, @LanceShi

Comment: Yep. So the issue is obviously in your multiselectpicklist component.

Comment: but when my multiselectpicklist is NULL (not have any record on it) my button still not work. i dont understand why multiselectpicklist disabled my button @LanceShi

Comment: You can post the component code and we can have a look

Comment: the solution is i create new page, @LanceShi

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the code, it looks like the whole code was not pasted, but here are some pointers which may help you resolving.

- Looks like the array / list that are used on your multiselect component are not initialized, you may want to initialize so that it works properly.
- Generally if the controller method is not called, the root cause would be a validation rule or some error. To catch that you can add a `<apex:pageMessages/>` to the page, it will display the errors / messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir! Yes, it just the necessary code that i think relevant for questioning in this forum @Avidev9
i already add value into my multiselectpicklist, but my button is disabled WHEN my multiselectpicklist is created. Then, i try to REMOVE my multiselectpicklist, and my button can work properly. I dont understand why, when i create multiselectpicklist in my vf page, my button doesn't work. Any idea?